# MySQL no numbers varchar sorting not working

Tags: mysql, sorting, varchar

My attendee_lastname column definition:
[image]
My sql:

```
SELECT attendee_lastname FROM oc_attendee ORDER BY attendee_lastname ASC
```

My Result:

[image]

I would expect lastname Abraham to be first?
Any ideas?

Comment: I think that first letter is not latin 'A'. Check `HEX(lastname)`.

Comment: Thank you Akina. Although that was not the problem, I did find the issue. The user typed a space before the last_name. So all those showing before Abraham had spaces in.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the User typed in a space before their last_name. This resulted in all those starting with spaces to be first on the list and then the rest. After removing all spaces it works perfectly.